# How to format data properly before using CDC_Transmit_FS?

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, usb, adc, c

I am using STM32CubeIDE to program 12 bit ADC(P/N = ADC128s102) which has 8 bit of control register and return 12 bit in MISO. Following is scope result. I am able to return some data which I think it is correct.. however, when I try to send these data to the terminal application using CDC_Transmit feature but i am definitely getting wrong value. I am trying to read in decimal and I am expecting value bewteen 1600~1700(ADC reference voltage is 5V). I am currently using only one channel and others grounded.
Could anyone provide me some guideline..? it's very simple thing but I've been struggling so long.. I think the way im reconstructing data is wrong.. thanks in advance

**SCOPE**
Yellow = MOSI

BLUE = CLK

GREEN = MISO

[image]

**MAIN LOOP**

[image]

**SPI INITILIZATION**
[image]

**Result on terminal**

32774
40710
29190
25094
37638
37126
32774
33798
41478
35590
45318
48134
40710
41222
47366
.....

**Edition 1**

```
 while (1)
  {
      //Put CS Low
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive(&hspi1, tx_data, rx_data, 1, 10);
      //Put CS High
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, SPI1_CS_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      //Reconstruction
      uint16_t adcval = (((uint16_t)rx_data[1]) << 8) | rx_data[0];
      sprintf(txBuf, "0x%X\t%d\r\n", adcval, adcval);
      CDC_Transmit_FS((uint8_t*)txBuf, strlen(txBuf));
      HAL_Delay(100);
  }
```

In terminal app,

```
0x649   1609
0x5F2   1522
0x5FD   1533
0x611   1553
0x632   1586
0x617   1559
0x61B   1563
0x643   1603
0x5FF   1535
0x62D   1581
0x64E   1614
0x62C   1580
0x5FB   1531
0x63D   1597
0x603   1539
0x5F9   1529
0x663   1635
0x61F   1567
0x5EB   1515
0x60C   1548
0x5F1   1521
0x629   1577
0x647   1607
```

Comment: So what have you done to debug the issue? Tried swapping the bytes? Comparing printed values to bit patterns seen on bus? Looked at CPU manual which way SPI does 16-bit transactions?

Comment: Please do not post source as screenshots. We cannot copy and paste these to reproduce your program. Please provide a minimal, complete and reproducible example that shows the issue. -- While you're [edit]ing your question, please add the result of an experiment, in which you transmit a fixed number via `CDC_Transmit_FS()`, for example by `uint16_t adcval = 12345`.

Comment: Why would there be a sudden hiccup on the MOSI line?

Comment: @Lundin This is a 1-bit in the data transferred from main to sub, see `uint8_t tx_data[] = {0x08, 0x00};`. I would not call it a hiccup, however, the offset in the call of `HAL_SPI_TransmitReceive()` might be wrong. SPI transfers in both directions at the same time.

Comment: @thebusybee Ah yeah, I didn't even bother reading the pictures. The offset seems wrong indeed, the 0x08 should appear earlier.

Comment: Also keep in mind the network endianess. With SPI, I would say big endian is far more common than little endian. But STM32 uses little endian.

Comment: The TX 0x00 and 0x08 are swapped becase you use SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT which suppose little-endian format, but you define your tx_data value as big-endian. Swap it and you will sense correct channel.

Comment: @thebusybee which offset are you referring in HAL_SPI_TranmistReceive()?

Comment: @Misaz dose SPI_DATASIZE_8Bit uses big endian format ?

Comment: When working with 8-bit data (single byte), there are no enadianess because endian define internal order of multi-byte value in the memory. But yes, from point of view of your program which use uint8_t buffer while working with uint16_t data, then yes, it works like big-endian.

Comment: Misaz thanks. I’ll give it a try. I do not have the board with me at this moment I’ll update once I try. Btw is there any issue with formatting the data when reconstructing data from reading? Like when I assign to adcval

Comment: the command which I provided in previous question still work in this setup. It will not work if you decide to switch tx_data/rx_data data type from uint8_t to uint16_t.

Comment: @Misaz I will not change datatype but in previous question you suggested to use SPI_DATASIZE_8BIT instead of 16bit.. that's where I was confused. In the current setup, it's using tx/rx_data uint8_t and SPI_DATASIZE_16BIT.

Comment: and if it's little-endian, shouldn't it be **uint16_t adcval = (((uint16_t)rx_data[1]) << 8) | rx_data[0];** instead of **uint16_t adcval = (((uint16_t)rx_data[0]) << 8) | rx_data[1];**?

Comment: no, the swap is here for fixing endianess. In case of tx buffer you swapped it by swapping 0x00 and 0x08 in tx arry. In case of reception you need to swap them also and this happen using command which I provided to you.

Comment: @Misaz understood. Ill try tonight. It makes more sense now. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, it was an misinterpretation of the parameters.

Comment: @Misaz so I had to do this **uint16_t adcval = (((uint16_t)rx_data[1]) << 8) | rx_data[0]; instead of uint16_t adcval = (((uint16_t)rx_data[0]) << 8) | rx_data[1];** as I mentioned in the comment. Please refer to edited post and results. Second byte of rx_data buffer will comprise of MSB and LSB in first byte of rx_data. Thus I had to swap them in order to display properly in terminal app. I am measuring analog input voltage around ~1.9V and adc_ref voltage is 5V with 12 bit of ADC. Thus these are correct value I am seeing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look closer at your scope shot, the control signals are in the wr0ng byte.

Your are sampling channel 0x00 and not the one you tried to select with the 0x08 value.

Fix is simple: Put it in the other byte, which is the MSB for a 16-bit value.

The ADC expects the control signals to be present in the first byte (MSB) sent on the wire.

EDIT:
Thuis is also why you see those funny values, the SPI peripherial/DMA corrects the byte order to little endian already for you and thus you combined the values the wrong way around. That would be much simpler to see if you printed the values in hex.